# Destroy Tkinter window in thread

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I have a project where a passive GUI runs in its own thread and is manipulated by the main thread. Especially, the window is closed by the main thread using `event_generate`:

```py
from tkinter import Tk
import threading
import time
import queue

q = queue.Queue()


class Window:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("test")
        self.root.bind("<<custom_close_event>>", self.close)

    def close(self, event):
        print("quit")
        self.root.destroy()


def create_window():
    window = Window()
    q.put(window)
    window.root.mainloop()
    print("###########")


# Window creation executed in different thread
t1 = threading.Thread(target=create_window)
t1.start()

window = q.get()

time.sleep(2)

window.root.event_generate("<<custom_close_event>>")

print("end")
```

The program crashes with the following output:

```
quit
###########
Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread
[1]    21572 IOT instruction (core dumped)  python window_test.py
```

According to [this discussion](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/271), it seems that the order of objects cleanup in multithreaded environment is in fault. The advice to nullify objects (in my case `window`) and to call `gc.collect` did not solve the problem.

How should I do?

Comment: You shouldn't access tkinter objects from a different thread.

Comment: `event_generate` can be safely called from another thread according to the [documentation](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/eventloop.html) (section Threads or Processes).

Comment: Yes but references to some objects remain which is why tcl crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @AndrewPye's answer but inheriting from `Tk` instead of `Toplevel`:

```py
from tkinter import *

class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        super().after(1000, self.do_something)

    def do_something(self):
        print("I am in a loop that runs every 1000ms = 1s")

        super().after(1000, self.do_something)

root = Window()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think you can just use `self.after`, no?

Comment: @Neraste yes but I would rather make it clear that I am using the `.after` method of the class that I am inheriting from.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a separate thread to create a second reference to Tk(),
Just inherit [tk.Toplevel](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/toplevel.html) when you create the "Window" class.
This will allow you to have really as many windows as you want.
You can use [tk.after](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-after-method-in-tkinter/) in order to monitor processes and do pseudo-multithreading things. Here's an example of how to do that

```
class Window(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        ...
        self.parent.after(1000, self.do_something)
 
    def do_something(self):
        ...
        <code>
        ...
        self.parent.after(1000, self.do_something)
    
root = Tk()
Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What should I pass as `parent` when creating an instance?

Comment: It can be whatever you want! Keep in mind that this window will get destroyed whenever the parent is destroyed (closed)

Comment: If I pass a `Tk` instance, I get 2 windows, which is not what I want…

Comment: Oh right. I slightly misunderstood what you asked. thought you wanted a separate window from your main window. But i guess you only wanted 1 window.